# how to add for example 5 empty rows after any of data band in The Stimulsoft Reporter?

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

As i mentioned in title, I want to add for example 5 rows after any data band in my report. I used empty band after any data band but i just only give one empty row.!! Is it possible to have more than one empty row after any data band in **The Stimulsoft Reporter**?
thanks for your help

Comment: about one day and steel no sulution!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a Data band with Count Data set to 5 as Detailed Band.